# Create a table of all invoices from Stripe API in PHP

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a table in PHP of all invoices in the table with the Stripe API.

This is my code so far:

```
$result = $stripe->invoices->all(['limit' => 100]);

echo $result;
```

I don't know how I can just display the invoice id, customer name and amount in a table. This is my first time working with Stripe and API's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't whether your question is more about the Stripe Invoice [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object), looping over all invoices (e.g. [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=php) or a PHP question on how to display a table. I concocted a response with all 3 of these things. I took the liberty to add some other info to the table as well.

```php
<?php
$invoices = $stripe->invoices->all([
    'limit' => 50,
]);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Invoice Id</th>
        <th>Customer Id</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Customer Email</th>
        <th>Amount Due</th>
        <th>Amount Paid</th>
        <th>Amount Remaining</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($invoices->autoPagingIterator() as $invoice) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $invoice['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $invoice['customer_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $invoice['customer_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $invoice['customer_email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $invoice['amount_due'] . $invoice['currency']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $invoice['amount_paid'] . $invoice['currency']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $invoice['amount_remaining'] . $invoice['currency']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $invoice['status']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Just wanted to pop back in and ask how can I make it so the amount that is shown is formatted and has like a dot between the cents value and the dollar value? Really sorry but just a bit new to this. Again thanks for your help.